# ¿Cómo dividir todas las observaciones de una base de datos por un valor en R?

Tags: r, funciones, algoritmos, base-de-datos

Tengo las siguientes variables en una base de datos:

```
names(mod1)
[1] "puntaje"     "constante"   "prom_sec"    "escol_madre" "escol_padre"
[6] "reg_sec"     "beca_sec"    "sexo_sus"    "presento"
```

Quiero aplicar de forma "manual" el procedimiento de mínimos cuadrados generalizados y para ello necesito dividir cada observación de cada variable por el recíproco de la desviación estándar del error (que ya calculé).
Supongamos que el valor que queremos aplicar es 1/x. Sabemos que para transformar cada variable de forma individual tenemos alternativas como mutate con dplyr:

```
BD <- mutate(BD, nuevo_nombre = variable*(1/x))
```

Por supuesto, esto es un poco tedioso si tienes muchas variables. ¿Existe algún procedimiento más rápido que permita dividir cada observación de cada variable por 1/x (o cualquier valor)?

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que tienes un dataframe "BD". 
Y que todas tus variables son del **tipo numérico**.
Creamos un nuevo dataframe "BDpaso2" que contiene el producto de cada elemento del dataframe "BD" por el factor (1/2):

```
BDpaso2<-BD*(1/2)
```

Esta es la forma más rápida.

Y si tu "x" es una variable cuyo número de filas es igual al número de filas del dataframe "BD". Puedes hacer esto tambien:

```
BDpaso2<-BD*(1/x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes una función:

```
escala_fun <- function(x) x/sd(x)
```

Y asumiendo que todas tus variables son numéricas puedes hacer:

```
BD <- mutate_all(BD, escala_fun)
```

Recuerda que `dplyr` posee otras funciones complementarias como `mutate_all` (mutar todo) o `mutate_if` (mutar si).

Ejemplo:

```r
library(dplyr)

d <- head(mtcars)
d
#>                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1

escala_fun <- function(x) x/sd(x)

d <- mutate_all(d, escala_fun)
d
#>        mpg      cyl     disp       hp     drat       wt     qsec       vs
#> 1 11.88891 4.743416 1.779694 3.781505 7.746272 5.655613 10.82160 0.000000
#> 2 11.88891 4.743416 1.779694 3.781505 7.746272 6.206064 11.18978 0.000000
#> 3 12.90796 3.162278 1.201293 3.197091 7.646961 5.008024 12.23512 1.825742
#> 4 12.11536 4.743416 2.869757 3.781505 6.117569 6.939998 12.78080 1.825742
#> 5 10.58679 6.324555 4.004311 6.016031 6.256605 7.425690 11.18978 0.000000
#> 6 10.24711 4.743416 2.502695 3.609619 5.481977 7.468863 13.29361 1.825742
#>         am     gear      carb
#> 1 1.825742 7.302967 2.7174649
#> 2 1.825742 7.302967 2.7174649
#> 3 1.825742 7.302967 0.6793662
#> 4 0.000000 5.477226 0.6793662
#> 5 0.000000 5.477226 1.3587324
#> 6 0.000000 5.477226 0.6793662

summarise_all(d, sd)
#>   mpg cyl disp hp drat wt qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1   1   1    1  1    1  1    1  1  1    1    1
```

Comment: Gracias. Creo que tendré que revisar nuevamente la documentación sobre dplyr para refrescar algunas cuestiones. ¡Saludos!